# Check & Return Columns that are only Characters in a Data Frame

Tags: r, dataframe

Is there a command to check and only return columns that are only Characters? 
I know `str(data_frame)` returns the structure of all columns in the data frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `Filter` from `base R`

```
Filter(is.character, df1)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = LETTERS[1:5], col2 = LETTERS[6:10], 
           col3 = 1:5, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```